# Sort csv imported dictionary based on an index position

Tags: python

I need to sort this csv file of superheroes by if they are a 'good' or 'neutral' character. I have tried to create an empty dictionary and add the information there with a for loop, however I keep getting repeats. I am not allowed to use anything like pandas btw.

This is the contents of the csv file:

```
Spider-Man (Peter Parker),Secret Identity,Good Characters,Living Characters,4043,Aug-62,1962
Captain America (Steven Rogers),Public Identity,Good Characters,Living Characters,3360,Mar-41,1941
Wolverine (James Logan Howlett),Public Identity,Neutral Characters,Living Characters,3061,Oct-74,1974
Iron Man (Anthony Tony Stark),Public Identity,Good Characters,Living Characters,2961,Mar-63,1963
Thor (Thor Odinson),No Dual Identity,Good Characters,Living Characters,2258,Nov-50,1950
Benjamin Grimm,Public Identity,Good Characters,Living Characters,2255,Nov-61,1961
Reed Richards,Public Identity,Good Characters,Living Characters,2072,Nov-61,1961
Hulk (Robert Bruce Banner),Public Identity,Good Characters,Living Characters,2017,May-62,1962
Scott Summers,Public Identity,Neutral Characters,Living Characters,1955,Sep-63,1963
Jonathan Storm,Public Identity,Good Characters,Living Characters,1934,Nov-61,1961
Henry McCoy,Public Identity,Good Characters,Living Characters,1825,Sep-63,1963
Susan Storm,Public Identity,Good Characters,Living Characters,1713,Nov-61,1961
Namor McKenzie,No Dual Identity,Neutral Characters,Living Characters,1528
```

The final result should look like:
{'Good Characters': [['Spider-Man (Peter Parker)', 'Secret Identity', 'Living Characters',
'4043', 'Aug-62', '1962'], ['Captain America (Steven Rogers)', 'Public Identity', 'Living
Characters', '3360', 'Mar-41', '1941']

'Neutral Characters': [['"Wolverine (James ""Logan"" Howlett)"', 'Public Identity', 'Living
Characters', '3061', 'Oct-74', '1974'],

The value of being a good or neutral character is in the second index position, however my code does not account for neutral characters nor does it remove the information from the second index position, here is my code:

```
 import csv

 def superheroes():

   f = open("Marvel_Windows.csv", 'r')
   reader = csv.reader(f)

   morality = {}
   for row in reader:
       morality[row[2]] = [row[0], row[1], row[3], row[4], row[5]]
       print(morality)
```

Comment: Try making a minimal example that others can execute. I.e. instead of import generate a small dataframe.

Comment: And also include sample input data that will be in the cvs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

def superheroes():

    f = open("Marvel_Windows.csv", 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    morality = {}
    for row in reader:
        key = row.pop(2)
        if key not in morality: # or you can use defaultdict
            morality[key] = [row]
        else:
            morality[key] = morality[key] + [row]
    print(morality)

superheroes()
```

{'Good Characters': [['Spider-Man (Peter Parker)', 'Secret Identity', 'Living Characters', '4043', 'Aug-62', '1962'], ['Captain America (Steven Rogers)', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '3360', 'Mar-41', '1941'], ['Iron Man (Anthony Tony Stark)', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '2961', 'Mar-63', '1963'], ['Thor (Thor Odinson)', 'No Dual Identity', 'Living Characters', '2258', 'Nov-50', '1950'], ['Benjamin Grimm', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '2255', 'Nov-61', '1961'], ['Reed Richards', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '2072', 'Nov-61', '1961'], ['Hulk (Robert Bruce Banner)', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '2017', 'May-62', '1962'], ['Jonathan Storm', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '1934', 'Nov-61', '1961'], ['Henry McCoy', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '1825', 'Sep-63', '1963'], ['Susan Storm', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '1713', 'Nov-61', '1961']], 'Neutral Characters': [['Wolverine (James Logan Howlett)', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '3061', 'Oct-74', '1974'], ['Scott Summers', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '1955', 'Sep-63', '1963'], ['Namor McKenzie', 'No Dual Identity', 'Living Characters', '1528']]}

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas would be the most sane way to do:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("Marvel_Windows.csv")
data['values'] = data.loc[:,data.columns!=3].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)).split(','),axis=1)
data.groupby(2)['values'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

results in:

```
{'Good Characters': [['Spider-Man (Peter Parker)', 'Secret Identity', 'Living Characters', '4043', 'Aug-62', '1962.0'], ['Captain America (Steven Rogers)', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '3360', 'Mar-41', '1941.0'], ['Iron Man (Anthony Tony Stark)', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '2961', 'Mar-63', '1963.0'],...
, 'Neutral Characters': [['Wolverine (James Logan Howlett)', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '3061', 'Oct-74', '1974.0'], ['Scott Summers', 'Public Identity', 'Living Characters', '1955', 'Sep-63', '1963.0'], ..}
```